cleanupInRocksdbCompactFilter method in Flink 1.15
I can't understand the 'queryTimeAfterNumEntries' parameter of the 'cleanupInRocksdbCompactFilter' method regarding TTL settings in Apache Flink 1.15.
Doc says:

Cleanup expired state while Rocksdb compaction is running.
RocksDB compaction filter will query current timestamp, used to check expiration, from Flink every time after processing queryTimeAfterNumEntries number of state entries. Updating the timestamp more often can improve cleanup speed but it decreases compaction performance because it uses JNI call from native code.
Parameters:
queryTimeAfterNumEntries - number of state entries to process by compaction filter before updating current timestamp

When does the compaction filter process state entries? How can I test the functioning of this cleanup strategy?

What would be your goal in testing this?

Because it seems to not working...the checkpoint size doesn't decrease

There are a few possible explanations for why your checkpoints aren't getting smaller.
There was a long-standing bug that was only recently fixed as part of Flink 1.20. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-26050 for more on that.
It's also important to keep in mind that RocksDB compaction is an ongoing, incremental process, that in some cases isn't happening very often. If your total state size isn't very large, it could be that RocksDB hasn't felt the need to compact yet, in which case your TTL strategy might not have had the chance to do anything.

Is it known how large the state size needs to be to start compaction? Any configuration data?

I add that, the checkpointSize drops a lot instead when I create a Savepoint (Snapshot in AWS KDA)

I read the Flink Jira card. I am having a hard time understanding the card but it seems that they have added an API to call manually to launch compaction. However, it does not seem to me that they have solved the problem of small files created by Timers. Can you explain this better for me?
